# Selenium in JMeter can't find element after redirecting to another page by clicking login button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to run JMeter tests using chrome driver config and Selenium. I opened login paged, logged in, clicked login button, the desired page has opened, but then selenium can't find ANY element on new opened page (page opened in SAME tab), writing "Response code:500 Response message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='node11828602']"}"

Page had enough time to load, I even added time sleep for 5 seconds
I tried different locators, CSS, xpath, id, nothing worked
Locators were correct and were finding only one targeted element
I thought it can be hidden iframe, but no, element was outside of iframes

Here's my code from WebDriver Sampler. First 8 rows work well

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get("url")
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("otds_username")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("otds_username")).sendKeys("login");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("otds_password")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("otds_password")).sendKeys("password");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("loginbutton")).click();


java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000)
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//a[@id='node11828602']")).click();
...
```

Comment: try `driver.getPageSource()` to see which page is driver working with. And if driver is not moving to next page, try `driver.navigate().forward()`

Comment: Also, don't use `Thread.sleep()`. Use implicit waits and/or explicit waits to time out after a particular condition is not met. For example, waiting for elements to become visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved only by installing Chrome and chromedriver v. 109 instead of v. 114

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything without seeing the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) of the page you're trying to interact with.

I can think of the following possible reasons:

- The element you're looking for may be in an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) so you need to [switch to it first](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo())
- The element you're looking for may be in [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM) so you need to locate the relevant [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) first and search for the element from this context

In general it's a good idea to use [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) instead of sleep. Also it worth checking [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for any suspicious entries